# filling part of an image in CSS

Tags: css, image, background

I'd like to create a scale with stars\flowers\whatever that will enable me to graphically present a fraction, in case of average grade (say 4.35). Is there a way to partially fill an empty non-rectangular image using CSS? 
TIA, Matanya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are okay with using a `div` instead of an `img` for the image, you could set the image as a background in the `div` element, and calculate the width of the div, depending on how much of the image you want to show.

The calculation would have to be done through JavaScript, or server-side and then added inline on the `div` element, though.

Comment: thanx. definitely a more elegant solution than my own.